# ART kills WebView before loading finished

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm trying to retrieve the html from a website that uses JavaScript. My method goes as follows:

- Create a headless WebView (without any view defined in the XML) and enable JS.
- Create a JavaScriptInterface with a method to be called when loading finishes.
- Override the onPageFinished method of the WebClientView I provide. The code here injects JavaScript to call the method I defined in my JavaScriptInterface, passing the html contents of the page as a parameter.

What's interesting is, this code works, but inconsistently. One time it would work as intended, and next time nothing would happen. I was getting all sorts of weird logcat messages, one of which I suspected could be a bad sign: `W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread`.
Today an idea popped to mind: Maybe sometimes my WebView gets killed because the runtime environment does optimizations (and my WebView has no XML View object linked to it)?

And so, I decided to try creating a WebView in my XML and use the same code with it instead of just creating one in the code. Right now the code works consistently, every time I run it, and I no longer receive those thread dumping log messages. As soon as I see the page finishes loading, the code would get executed.

Do note, I noticed this specific website I'm referencing takes relatively long time to load (as long as a few seconds), and also onPageFinished gets called more than once, delivering the html with unprocessed JS unless it is the last call.

So, my questions is: Is there any way to prevent ART from dumping my thread when using the headless version (or any other workaround)? I thought of keeping the WebView defined in the XML, and setting its visibility to false, but it seems like a resource-heavy solution.

I'm working with the Android Emulator (although I got the same results using a physical device as well), target API is 24, minimum API 15.

Relevant code:

```
private void fetchHTML(View view, String url) {
    class JSInterface{
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void processHTML(String html){
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, html); // This bit of code sometimes gets executed, and sometimes does not
        }
    }
    //final WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    final WebView webView = new WebView(context);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "Android");
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if(webView.getProgress() == 100){
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.Android.processHTML("
                        + "'<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
            }
        }
    });

    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Relevant logcat when not executed properly:

```
07-15 17:16:27.616 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa-2/lib/x86
07-15 17:16:28.214 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa-2/lib/x86
07-15 17:16:28.267 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-15 17:16:28.448 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.webview version 44.0.2403.119 (code 246011910)
07-15 17:16:28.456 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/webview/lib/x86
07-15 17:16:28.465 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa I/LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 3 ms (timestamps 8656-8659)
07-15 17:16:28.465 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa I/LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
07-15 17:16:28.470 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider: Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {c4bffce}
07-15 17:16:28.470 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa I/LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
07-15 17:16:28.470 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(120)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
07-15 17:16:28.476 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa I/BrowserStartupController: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
07-15 17:16:28.479 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
07-15 17:16:28.479 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
07-15 17:16:28.484 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/chromium: [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(285)] locale_file_path.empty()
07-15 17:16:28.487 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
07-15 17:16:28.487 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

                                                                [ 07-15 17:16:28.488 17779:17779 D/         ]
                                                                HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xac3edff0, tid 17779
07-15 17:16:28.525 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008d57
07-15 17:16:28.552 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa E/DataReductionProxySettingListener: No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
07-15 17:16:28.568 17779-17831/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/AudioManagerAndroid: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
07-15 17:16:28.578 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
07-15 17:16:28.582 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
07-15 17:16:28.584 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
07-15 17:16:28.585 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
07-15 17:16:28.587 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
07-15 17:16:28.587 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
07-15 17:16:28.620 17779-17841/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-15 17:16:28.639 17779-17829/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/chromium: [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_config.cc(423)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
07-15 17:16:28.740 17779-17841/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

                                                                        [ 07-15 17:16:28.741 17779:17841 D/         ]
                                                                        HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa0a5f8d0, tid 17841
07-15 17:16:28.782 17779-17841/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-15 17:16:28.782 17779-17841/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaa3d9180, error=EGL_SUCCESS

                                                                        [ 07-15 17:16:28.815 17779:17850 D/         ]
                                                                        HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa0c82c80, tid 17850
07-15 17:16:29.166 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 17779
07-15 17:16:29.279 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa D/MovieGridFragment: 
07-15 17:16:29.768 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 17779
07-15 17:16:30.894 17779-17779/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined", source:  (2)
07-15 17:16:31.196 17779-17829/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/chromium: [WARNING:spdy_session.cc(2527)] Received WINDOW_UPDATE for invalid stream 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the idea I proposed, I kept the XML-defined WebView (with visibility set to "gone") and used it instead of creating it at runtime. I haven't had any issues since.